# Capitalizing a String

Tags: javascript, chunks

I'm aware of the CSS attribute `text-transform: capitalize` but can anyone help me with replicating this using Javascript?

I would like to pass an argument to my function which will return the string with the first letter of each word capitalized.

I've got this far but I'm stuck trying to break my array of strings in to chunks:

```
function upper(x){
  x = x.split(" "); 

  // this function should return chunks but when called I'm getting undefined
  Array.prototype.chunk = function ( n ) {
      return [ this.slice( 0, n ) ].concat( this.slice(n).chunk(n) );
  };

  x = x.chunk;

}

upper("chimpanzees like cigars")
```

after the chunk I'm guessing I need to again split each chunk in to the first character and the remaining characters, use `.toUpperCase()` on the first character, join it back up with the remaining and then join up the chunks again in to a string?

Is there a simpler method for doing this?

Comment: because I only want to capitalize the first letter of each word, not the whole word

Comment: @rocket got it , sorry missed that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `map` function is perfect for this.

`w[0].toUpperCase()` : Use this to capitalize the first letter of each word

`w.slice(1)`: Return the string from the second character on

**EDGE Case**

If the user doesn't enter a string, the `map` function will not work and an error will be raised. This can be  guarded against by checking if the user actually entered something.

```js
var userInput = prompt("Enter a string");

var capitalizedString = userInput == "" ? "Invalid String" :
 userInput.split(/\s+/).map(w => w[0].toUpperCase() + w.slice(1)).join(' ');

console.log(capitalizedString);
```

Comment: Try to enter the following string: "I love USA!". It is not wise to alter the rest of the string. Why are you assuming it's okay to lowercase all letters after the first? You should just remove the `.toLowerCase()` part.

Comment: @connexo absolutely nothing. That's why I just removed it

Answer (score 4):

I came up with a solution for both a *single* word and also for an *array* of words. It will also ensure that all other letters are lowercase for good measure. I used the Airbnb style guide as well. I hope this helps!

```js
const mixedArr = ['foo', 'bAr', 'Bas', 'toTESmaGoaTs'];
const word = 'taMpa';

function capitalizeOne(str) {
  return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase().concat(str.slice(1).toLowerCase());
}


function capitalizeMany(args) {
  return args.map(e => {
    return e.charAt(0).toUpperCase().concat(e.slice(1).toLowerCase());
  });
};

const cappedSingle = capitalizeOne(word);
const cappedMany = capitalizeMany(mixedArr);

console.log(cappedSingle);
console.log(cappedMany);
```

Comment: You could reuse your capitalizeOne


`function capitalizeMany(args){return args.map(e => capitalizeOne(e))}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution which doesn't use regex.

```
function capitalize(str=''){
  return str.trim().split('')
    .map((char,i) => i === 0 ? char.toUpperCase() : char )
    .reduce((final,char)=> final += char, '' )
  }

capitalize(' hello')                     // Hello
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"abcd efg ijk lmn".replace(/\b(.)/g, (m => m.toUpperCase())) // Abcd Efg Ijk Lmn
```

Comment: Technically great, but this answer could really be improved by an explanation making the brilliance within accessible to a wider range of people. Code only answers can almost always be improved by the addition of some explanation. Explain how and why this works and it improves its value as an answer immensely.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try a regex approach:

```
function upperCaseFirst(value) {
    var regex = /(\b[a-z](?!\s))/g;
    return value ? value.replace(regex, function (v) {
      return v.toUpperCase();
    }) : '';
}
```

This will grab the first letter of every word on a sentence and capitalize it, but if you only want the first letter of the sentence, you can just remove the `g` modifier at the end of the regex declaration.

Answer (score 0):

or you could just iterate the string and do the job:

```
function capitalize(lowerStr){
  var result = "";
  var isSpacePrevious = false;
  for (var i=0; i<lowerStr.length; i++){
      if (i== 0 || isSpacePrevious){
         result += lowerStr[i].toUpperCase();
         isSpacePrevious = false;
         continue;
      }
      if (lowerStr[i] === ' '){
          isSpacePrevious = true;
      }  
      result +=  lowerStr[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```